# How can I change the pH level?

Tags: acid-base, home-experiment

I am conducting a experiment that needs a pH 5 sulfuric acid but I only have pH 3 sulfuric acid. I have some distilled water and a graduated cylinder but I do not know how I can change it.

Comment: Can you convert pH 3 into a concentration of sulfuric acid?

Comment: yes @orthocresol

Comment: Do so, then. And do the same for the pH 5 sulfuric acid..

Comment: If you wish, you can answer your own question using whatever method you have found works for you. Answering your own question is recommended here.